# Entity Framework Core Can't Add Entity but can Select it

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

My problem is:

I can select a entity normally, but when a try to add it, i'm receiving the exception:

```
ORA-06550: linha 3, coluna 22:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: linha 3, coluna 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Context below:

My database: Oracle
Owner (schema that have the data): XXX
User on connect (user that have permissions to select, insert, etc): YYY.

I'm ensure the grants its ok. I can insert mannualy the data.

My Entity on my API it's declared like:

[Table("TABLE_NAME", Schema = "XXX")]
public class AnalyzeFeedback

[Select ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suT7C.jpg)

```
            IQueryable<AnalyzeFeedback> analyzeFeedbacks = dbContext.AnalyzeFeedbacks;

            var query = (from u in analyzeFeedbacks
                         select u);

            var sql = query.ToSql();

            var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

This select returns the first record of my table. Perfectly.

When I try to add a new record:

Insert problem:
[Exception on SaveChanges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu6QY.jpg)

```
        dbContext.AnalyzeFeedbacks.Add(feedback);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

On "SaveChanges" it's when i'm getting the error.

Sorry if i'm not clear enough on my explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please replace the screenshots with text. Also a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that thisis the only one object added to dbContext? Try to invoke `dbContext.SaveChanges()` right before adding. Also does `AnalyzeFeedback` have any reference properties/fields?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
clarify title of question, more details or clarify of problem, improve text arragement, include error message, improve code formatting,
 provide more information about the problem: 
results
,
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

> Also does AnalyzeFeedback have any reference properties/fields

This is exactly my problem man, thanks.

My entity have a property that not correctly tagged:

```
[ForeignKey("AnalyzeId")]
public Analyze Analyze { get; set; }

[NotMapped] <<< this!
public List<AnalyzeFeedbackBasement> Basements { get; set; }
```

When a tagged like "NotMapped", the insert occoured like expected.

Thanks for your reply Gullard!!